# Meaning of the done() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let us suppose you have the following action

```
export const startAddExpense = (expenseData = {}) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const {
      description = '',
      note = '',
      amount = 0,
      createdAt = 0
    } = expenseData;
    const expense = { description, note, amount, createdAt };

    return database.ref('expenses').push(expense).then((ref) => {
      dispatch(addExpense({
        id: ref.key,
        ...expense
      }));
    });
  };
};
```

I am storing expenses data to a database(firebase in my case) and then I dispatch the **addExpense** function to the store

And here the test for it.

```
test('should add expense to database and store', (done) => {
    const store = createMockStore({});
    const expenseData = {
      description: 'Mouse',
      amount: 3000,
      note: 'This one is better',
      createdAt: 1000
    };

    store.dispatch(startAddExpense(expenseData)).then(() => {
      expect(1).toBe(1);
      done();
    });
});
```

What is the meaning of the done() function? Does it mean the callback function should wait until the insertion of data in the firebase database has been completed?

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: I thought that was from Mocha (or whatever your test framework is). Is ReactJS relevant here?

Comment: @VLAZ yes it is.

Comment: OK, so `done` can *only* be used with React, not with any other async code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`done` mean that your test function has **asynchronous** code. So you should manually call `done` when you get an async result. Also, async tests have third parameters that define timeout after that function would be considered as failed.
https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async#callbacks